# Angular with Bootstrap and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I want use Bootstrap with his components on Angular.

I found ng-bootstrap that is for Angular, but can I use normal Bootstrap with jQuery? Because I need to use https://bootstrap-table.com/ that requires Bootstrap with jQuery, or do you recommend another table extension?

Isn't it recommended to use jQuery in Angular?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
you can use bootstrap and jQuery in angular,
but it's more recommended to use ng-bootstrap,
it has fewer bugs.

If you still decided to use bootstrap and jQuery,
install both packages and add them in the angular.json file.

[Documentation on how to install bootstrap in Angular](https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/)

You also need to install jQuery to use bootstrap
[Here is the documentation](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176)

You can also use Angular Material 
(But personly, I prefer to use ng-bootstrap).
[See how to install and use in the official website](https://material.angular.io/)

Answer (score 0):

from command line you can run this:

```
npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save-dev
```

and then edit angular.json and add jQuery & bootstrap js files to the scripts section